# return back original pointer from dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

```
auto &element = *std::make_unique<Source_Element>();
    auto n = sfElements.size();
    element.setIndex(n);
    element.setCurve(curve);

    sfElements.push_back(std::move(*element)); // -> this doesn't work
```

I tried `auto element = std::make_unique<Source_Element>();`  then , `sfElements.push_back(std::move(element));` it works just fine

Dereferring unique pointer result in getting Source_Element Class. then it goes into element value.
but I am wondering there is anyway to get the original pointer which is unique pointer from 
dereferenced pointer(which is Source_Element Class) just like a code i wrote on top

Comment: `auto &element = *std::make_unique<Source_Element>();` means "give me an invalid reference". Sorry, couldn't understand the rest.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are you trying to get the underlying raw pointer ?

Comment: What you have is bad in multiple ways. First of all there is no way to get the `std::unique_ptr` object from the reference you have to the wrapped object. What's worse is that by using `*std::make_unique<Source_Element>()` you are creating a ***temporary*** `std::unique_ptr` object, that will be destructed once the assignment is over leaving you with a reference to a destructed object and *undefined behavior*.

Comment: just use `element` and `element->` instead of `*element` and `element.` everywhere in this code snippet. Otherwise you'll get undefined behaviour, as @Some programmer dude noted above. And remove `&` and `*` from the first snippet line as well.

Comment: Share// I am trying to get back pointer created from this line "auto &element = *std::make_unique<Source_Element>();"

Comment: @user7375792 Since you do not place this unique_ptr to any object, it's destroyed right after creation. There is nothing to 'get back' after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way.

For any object in C++, there could be an arbitrary number of pointers pointing to it (including those wrapped by smart pointers), but the object itself doesn't automatically know about them. Pointers are unidirectional.

That is, if you dereference a `std::unique_ptr<T>` to get the underlying `T`, then the `T` itself will not know where it came from.

---

Your code also contains a few mistakes, most notably that `auto &element = *std::make_unique<Source_Element>();` doesn't make sense, because you try create a reference to a temporary object.